# Can the bootstrap servers be changed without restarting the KAFKA clients?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

KAFKA clients (producer & consumer) discover the topology by connecting to one the configured bootstrap server and from then on it will work with those set of broker nodes in the cluster directly.

With that standard thing, can we change producer and consumer without restarting them to work with different cluster by changing the bootstrap servers? Can we change the bootstrap server Config without restarting the clients?

There is a client config called metadata.max.age.ms which will force the client to refresh the broker topology but that covers only new partition leader and new broker node added to the cluster.

This is mainly to cover the scenario where KAFKA Cluster in a DC is down for some unexpected reason and clients from the same DC who already established connection with the same DC KAFKA cluster and want to explore the option of redirecting already started KAFKA clients to work with other DC KAFKA cluster in case same DC cluster is down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the configured bootstrap servers in the official Kafka Client.

Clients are able to discover the full Kafka cluster from the initial bootstrap servers and will periodically refresh this data (every `metadata.max.age.ms`) but they cannot be moved to another cluster on the fly.

As you mentioned, clients will need to be restarted pointing to the new cluster.

Comment: This is what we guessed it. Thank you! Before I accept this answer just wanted to check.                                                                                                                                      When you say "You cannot change the configured bootstrap servers in the official Kafka Client" is there any extension point available via inheritance etc to implement the desired feature of changing the bootstrap servers on the fly (upon a timeout etc )

Comment: I'm not aware of any extensions (or 3rd party clients) that allow it.

Comment: In such a scenario what if I use 1st broker URL in the bootstrap list from DC 1 and other broker URL from DC 2?

Comment: bootstrap servers entries are shuffled before being used (to avoid always connecting to the 1st entry) so the behaviour you'll get will be random